# Making IK with objects NOT bones

Tags: animation, objects

I have a robotic arm. Pieces are separate objects. They are right now on a FK Hierechy.

Can I add an empty object for target and then turning them into IK? How?

I´ve been searching on the internet but IK seems to work only with bones. Can I do IK with a simple objects chain? I come from lightwave where I know how to do it, but in Blender can´t find anything on the subject.

Comment: if you try to give an IK to an object, it says: "IK constraint can only be added to bones."

Comment: Any other way to make IK on objects? it seems way too hard to make the structure in pieces and then again create an armature an assign weights and check the deformation instead of just parenting pieces together.

Comment: you can simply parent the object to a bone: ctrl P > Bone instead of With Automatic Weight

Comment: Only bones have IK chain solvers. Parenting an object to a bone is not difficult as moonboots said. And you could snap the newly created bones to some reference faces or vertices (where the joints are).

Comment: What I mean is that not only I have to build the whole robot arm but again i need to make bones and placethem accordingly? Is that correct?

Comment: There isn´t a single bone in this test I made. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DUPWIhjEOHc there´s no approach like this on blender?

Comment: Ok, If i got this correctly, there´s no way in blender I can make IK using only the objects I modeled?

Comment: There are object constraints that you could probably use to make something akin to IK but it'd be a lot more complicated than just making a rig for it and following any IK tutorial on youtube. You wouldn't need to remake the whole arm. You just have to create the armature, unparent the objects from each other while keeping the offset and then parent them to the bones as an object like in this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vZaNZhAoMts

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can parent bones to an IK object. In pose mode, select the bone you want to parent to the object, then at the top of the screen go back into pose, go down to inverse kinematics - Add IK to bone - parent to empty object.

Now you have an object parented to that bone. You can go back into pose mode, select the parented bone and look and ik bone constraints, you will see you now have an option for ik chain. chain as many bones as needed. If you want to change/lock rotations, look at the bone section, then go to the inverse kinematics section and modify your rotations there ( if you have tried to setup bone constraints as a modifier,they won't work with IK, if you have them delete them all and just modify the rotations under bone-inverse kinematics.)
You can also select the parent bone and there is a check box for inheret rotation. I personally like to have that checked.

Now you are using an object to manipulate your armature, meaning you cant be in pose mode to make changes. In object mode, you should be able to move your objects around and see the armature follow the path you choose, based on the rotation limits you've set.

So to create an animation. go to pose mode, select all bones. Crtl+I - insert keyframe for loc,rot,scale. This will lock in your start position.

Now go back to object mode, make sure record is on (It should be a red dot, but it is just a dot next to the play/rewind controls.) manipulate your objects as you see fit, go back to pose mode, select the frame you want to keyframe (i.e how long do you want it to take to get from your first pose to the one we are about to enter), once you have selected the frame ctrl+A select all bones ctrl+I insert keyframe again loc,rot,scale.

Look i'm no teacher, i just figure i understand what your asking a bit better than other answers